# SHA512 hash in Oracle PLSQL vs Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, encryption, sha512

I need to get a hash in Ora PL-SQL thats the same as it is in Node.js using crypto module.
In PLSQL im using integrated dbms_crypto.hash function. There is also dbms_crypto.mac function but i cant use it since there is no additional secret to use for hashing.

All 3 methods i've tried returned different results from Node crypto module.

```
  declare   
   v_body varchar2(1000):= 'myteststring';
   v_hash varchar2(1000); 
  begin
--1 method
 SELECT  sys.dbms_crypto.hash( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_body),  DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH512 ) 
 INTO v_hash
 FROM dual; 
 dbms_output.put_line(lower((v_hash)));
 --result:516e7933c5ecd0721cd91cdbe341834ffe775bb32a223faa5c564d3ddf0b3069bdebfde2f07b642bad5f1351ec913247c737855ba8adf03cb56adc76ca3c8722
 
 --2 method
 SELECT standard_hash (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_body), 'SHA512')
 INTO v_hash
 FROM dual; 
 dbms_output.put_line(lower(v_hash));
 --result:516e7933c5ecd0721cd91cdbe341834ffe775bb32a223faa5c564d3ddf0b3069bdebfde2f07b642bad5f1351ec913247c737855ba8adf03cb56adc76ca3c8722

 --3 method
 SELECT standard_hash (rawtohex(v_body), 'SHA512')
 INTO v_hash
 FROM dual; 
 dbms_output.put_line(lower((v_hash)));
 --result:7dcaa1fd7e41a572158ec8a3742599f9e34ddd33d649e1952223780863ee66a6722ad93091cc6e42f53e16f896e130ac4e28794affde34819e32e77873c2ed46
 end;
```

In Node.js code is simple and looks like this (this is other side and cant change this):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var mystring = 'myteststring';
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512',mystring).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
//22e6584b717cff0f6180bf988c5ebf0bbb0bc1959bbb911a203f9188971fc2de93b6c83465501747d1cde6f6efaf0b37d4ac278bcd3bb6fe662d3e9f7e0ae50c
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong, or this Ora function works different. I've also tried changing type of parameters (clob/varchar). Ora result is in hex as its in Node.
Thanks in any advance!

Comment: From the docs, in your Node example `myteststring` is the secret key, not the data to be hashed. Are you also calling update with a real value to hash? (And do you need HMAC or just a plain hash? i.e. are you trying to replicate an existing HMAC that you're stuck with, or inventing something new? dbms_crypto can create HMAC if you need it, but you need both the key and the data...)

Comment: Node sample is service on the other side and it works like its written (cant change that).  Yes i need to use HMAC or MAC in Oracle but if i use dbms_crypto.mac like this:

sys.dbms_crypto.mac( utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myteststring'),  5 ,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myteststring'))   

It takes secret and data and that returns different result since there is not possible to use just secret in this package.

Comment: But what data is the Node version actually hashing? Your example doesn't show any data (i.e. no update or stream).

Comment: @mire.ba Your Node.js code may give you an output but you are passing a string as the secret key and then not hashing any message. At first glance that looks to be the wrong approach.

Comment: Its not different approach, its just the way they compare hashes. Its actually HMAC auth for payment API and API doc is here: https://ipgtest.monri.com/en/documentation/pay_by_link#requests-authentication

Comment: OK, so if that's what you're stuck with then you have a problem in Oracle; as empty string and null are the same, trying to hash an empty string (which is what your Node version is doing) gives a null result.

Comment: @mire.ba They're doing it wrong ... it should be `var digest = crypto.createHmac('sha512',merchantKey + timestamp + authenticityToken + fullpath).update(body).digest('hex');`  However, since you're stuck with what you are doing then use `NULL` for the source to `DBMS_CRYPTO.MAC`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote i need hash in PLSQL but seems like there's something different in using ORA functions from dbms_crypto package since it requests more params. Thanks!

Comment: "there's something different" - nn, you're mixing up hash and HMAC, as already said; *those* are different. Your Node version is giving the HMAC for an empty string, using your data as the key. Trying to get that in Oracle gives a null result.

Comment: Its not null, its different result if use HMAC in oracle like this:
 sys.dbms_crypto.mac( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(null),  5 ,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myteststring'))
//7dcaa1fd7e41a572158ec8a3742599f9e34ddd33d649e1952223780863ee66a6722ad93091cc6e42f53e16f896e130ac4e28794affde34819e32e77873c2ed46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work if you call the CLOB (or BLOB) overload of dbms_crypto.mac and pass an empty clob (or blob), e.g.

```
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (
        dbms_crypto.mac (
            src => EMPTY_CLOB (),
            typ => dbms_crypto.hmac_sh512,
            key => utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('myteststring')));
END;
/

22E6584B717CFF0F6180BF988C5EBF0BBB0BC1959BBB911A203F9188971FC2DE93B6C83465501747D1CDE6F6EFAF0B37D4AC278BCD3BB6FE662D3E9F7E0AE50C
```

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, you are using `createHmac` rather than `createHash`.

If you use:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
var mystring = 'myteststring';
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(mystring).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> 516e7933c5ecd0721cd91cdbe341834ffe775bb32a223faa5c564d3ddf0b3069bdebfde2f07b642bad5f1351ec913247c737855ba8adf03cb56adc76ca3c8722
> ```

Which matches the output of your first two Oracle queries.

---

If you want to generate a HMAC then in Node.js you want:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
var mystring = 'myteststring';
var secret = 'mysecret';
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret).update(mystring).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

and in Oracle, you want (untested):

```sql
DECLARE
  v_body varchar2(1000):= 'myteststring';
  v_key  varchar2(1000):= 'mysecret';
  v_hash varchar2(1000); 
BEGIN
  SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.MAC(
           src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_body),
           typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.HMAC_SH512,
           key => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_key)
         ) 
  INTO   v_hash
  FROM   DUAL; 

  dbms_output.put_line(lower((v_hash)));
END;
/
```

For your code you would want a `NULL` message (again, untested):

```sql
DECLARE
  v_body varchar2(1000):= NULL;
  v_key  varchar2(1000):= 'myteststring';
  v_hash varchar2(1000); 
BEGIN
  SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.MAC(
           src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_body),
           typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.HMAC_SH512,
           key => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_key)
         ) 
  INTO   v_hash
  FROM   DUAL; 

  dbms_output.put_line(lower((v_hash)));
END;
/
```

Comment: Thats right, but Node.js sample is one that works like its written and i cant change that. Its service on other side that takes my hash and compare it on the way i wrote.  I need to adjust my oracle process. Thanks!

Comment: @mire.ba Then use `DBMS_CRYPTO.MAC(src,typ,key)` and pass in the secret key. (Updated)

Comment: I've tried but cant, since it require additional parameter (key or secret), but Node example doesnt, it just create hash from one string (whatever its called secret or string).

Comment: @mire.ba That is because your Node.js code is setting the secret key and then not hashing any message. That appears to be the wrong way of doing things. You should be providing both a secret key in Node.js and a message. You can try passing in a `NULL` value to the `src` argument in Oracle.

Comment: I've tried but result is not the same. sys.dbms_crypto.mac( utl_raw.cast_to_raw(null),  5 ,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('myteststring'))
Parameter int 5 is actually HMAC_SH512